# ddev snapshot fails with bash "Is a directory" error

Tags: ddev

I have several DDEV sites. Each one has multiple git branches, with a snapshot on each branch. Before I change a branch, I delete the snapshot and take a new one. The branches randomly start to fail ddev snapshot.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ddev snapshot --name=main
Creating database snapshot main 
bash: /var/tmp/main-mysql_5.7.gz: Is a directory 
Failed to create snapshot: composeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-hcanews docker-compose -f /home/hca/sites/hcanews/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml exec -T db bash -c set -eu && ( set -eu -o pipefail; xtrabackup --backup --stream=xbstream --user=root --password=root --socket=/var/tmp/mysql.sock  2>/tmp/snapshot_main-mysql_5.7.gz.log | gzip > "/var/tmp/main-mysql_5.7.gz" )', action='[]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='bash: /var/tmp/main-mysql_5.7.gz: Is a directory', stdout=, stderr=bash: /var/tmp/main-mysql_5.7.gz: Is a directory 
Failed to snapshot hcanews: composeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-hcanews docker-compose -f /home/hca/sites/hcanews/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml exec -T db bash -c set -eu && ( set -eu -o pipefail; xtrabackup --backup --stream=xbstream --user=root --password=root --socket=/var/tmp/mysql.sock  2>/tmp/snapshot_main-mysql_5.7.gz.log | gzip > "/var/tmp/main-mysql_5.7.gz" )', action='[]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='bash: /var/tmp/main-mysql_5.7.gz: Is a directory' `
```

ddev debug test gist here:
https://gist.github.com/misthufe/4f2b509cd29747a288c7d6532ca4ece0

This error is happening when I run my script:

```
# Delete snapshot...
verbose "$LINENO" "ddev snapshot --cleanup --name $SNAPSHOT"
echo -e "/usr/bin/ddev snapshot --cleanup --name $SNAPSHOT" >> "$LOG"
/usr/bin/ddev snapshot --cleanup --name "$SNAPSHOT"

verbose $LINENO
separator
# Create snapshot...
verbose "$LINENO" "ddev snapshot --name=$SNAPSHOT"
echo -e "/usr/bin/ddev snapshot --name=$SNAPSHOT" >> "$LOG"                                                                         
/usr/bin/ddev snapshot --name="$SNAPSHOT"
```

Is there a way to change the script so it doesn't happen?

Comment: Could you please say what operating system you're on and what database type you're working with (mysql?). Better yet, do `ddev debug test` and capture the output and provide it as a gist on gist.github.com. Maybe you're on colima, which can refuse to mount a file and tries to mount it as a directory.

Comment: ddev debug test gist here: https://gist.github.com/misthufe/4f2b509cd29747a288c7d6532ca4ece0

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, it makes sense. Have you already tried deleting anything you don't want in the project .ddev/db_snapshots directory? Is there a directory named main-mysql_5.7.gz in there? Whatever is there, please delete it and try again. Are you really running Fedora 6.5.10?  I don't know Fedora very well, but isn't that about 16 years ago?

Comment: In all of my .ddev/db_snapshots directories, there are only *-mysql_5.7.gz files, no directories. Running Fedora 38.

Comment: Edited question to add script snippet.

Comment: Thanks. Are you really running an ancient version of Fedora? Not sure how you could.

Comment: Oh, I see it says elsewhere, Fedora Linux 38

Comment: I note that you have `omit_containers: [dba]` - that's very obsolete, consider doing `ddev config --auto` to update your project configuration. Also please update to DDEV v1.22.5, just so we're on the same page.

Comment: It looks to me like docker is not keeping up with what you're doing. The `ddev snapshot --cleanup` deletes the file, which is normally mounted into the container. I think if you did a `ddev restart` or perhaps even a sleep here before creating the new snapshot it might be better.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help -- and an amazing product!